# Why does calculating an interest rate in python with loop and formula differ?

Tags: python, math

I'm currently designing a simple interest calculator but I am trying simple calculations where the results are similar but should be the same.

For example:
I start with 50 000$ and have a interest rate of 10% over the course of 5 years. The result with the classic formula looks like this: 50 000$ * 1,10^5 = 80 525,5$

But with python i get the following result:

```
kapital_from_start = 50000.00
intrest_rate_per_year = 10.00
intrest_rate_per_month = (((intrest_rate_per_year / 12.0) / 100.0) + 1.0)
additional_monthly_increase = 00.00
duration_in_years = 5.0
duration_in_months = duration_in_years * 12.0

i = 1
result = 0.0
while i <= duration_in_months:
    if i == 1: #First month.
        result = kapital_from_start * intrest_rate_per_month
    else:
        result *= intrest_rate_per_month
    i += 1

print("\n\n######################################################\n")
print("Resulting kapital: " + str(result) + " $.")
print("\n######################################################\n\n")
```

I am getting the result: 82265,44673892925
Which is give or take 82 300$ instead of 80 525,5$

Does anyone know what is going on with these numbers? Why do they differ so much?
If my calculations are correct, does that mean that actually looping trough these interest rates is more accurate than the formula which school books provide and banks have on their homepages for people to calculate their rates?

Comment: The iterative approach is compounding interest monthly.

Comment: Should that make a difference? Is it more accurate? @wallyk

Comment: It makes a difference because that's not how compounding works. IF you insist on using a monthly loop, then the monthly interest rate shouldn't be the yearly one divided by 12. Rather, it should be the 12th root of the yearly one.

Comment: @wallyk gave the correct answer. Any calculation I've seen for monthly interest rate is `percent_i/12`

Comment: Interesting, I've never done it with a squareroot of anykind like this before. Then again, I've only been using years for now but I have to change to month unfortunatly. Should my third line of code look like this then? : `interest_rate_per_month = (((interest_rate_per_year ** (1/12)) / 100.0) + 1.0)` @Lagerbaer

Comment: @MaxPower Well do you get the correct result with that?

Comment: @ChrisCharley I'd say that always depends on the terms / conditions of the financial institution. If you want to achieve the same total outcome of yearly interest but in terms of monthly interest, you have to use the 12-th root. But often, a company tells you something is "x% annually" but they mean "x/12 % monthly".

Comment: @MaxPower Your order of operations is off. It should be `interest_rate_per_month = (interest_rate_per_year / 100.0 + 1)**(1/12))`

Comment: Perfect! Now i get the same result with the updated order of operations. Thanks for the input @Lagerbaer

Comment: @Lagerbaer Yes I agree it depends on the terms of the institution as you said. But I think many ones do divide the annual rate by 12 to get the monthly rate (which compound for a year gives a greater yield than the stated annual percentage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize everythin written in the comments:

If you use a [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) your function is exponential and not linear. Meaning that divinding the yearly rate will not make it.

You should try to think as, what monthly compound interest applied 12 times will be the same as the whole year. This in an equation form would be something like:

```
yearly = monthly **12 # Because this is compound there is an exponential

# That´s equivalent to

monthly = yearly ** (1/12)
```

So you just need to change your calculation of the monthly interest.

```
intrest_rate_per_month = ((intrest_rate_per_year / 100) + 1) ** (1/12)
```

And the final code with the correct result

```py
kapital_from_start = 50000.00
intrest_rate_per_year = 10.00
intrest_rate_per_month = ((intrest_rate_per_year / 100) + 1) ** (1/12)
additional_monthly_increase = 00.00
duration_in_years = 5.0
duration_in_months = duration_in_years * 12.0

i = 1
result = 0.0
while i <= duration_in_months:
    if i == 1: #First month.
        result = kapital_from_start * (intrest_rate_per_month)
    else:

        result *=intrest_rate_per_month

    i += 1

print("\n\n######################################################\n")
print("Resulting kapital: " + str(result) + " $.")
print("\n######################################################\n\n")
```

---

#### Cleaning the code

Also take into account that you could just make a non iterative solution, getting rid of this while loop, so this piece of code:

```
result = kapital_from_start * (intrest_rate_per_month) ** duration_in_months
```

Gets rid of this whole while loop:

```
i = 1
result = 0.0
while i <= duration_in_months:
    if i == 1: #First month.
        result = kapital_from_start * (intrest_rate_per_month)
    else:

        result *=intrest_rate_per_month

    i += 1
```

With a final code resulting in:

```
kapital_from_start = 50000.00
intrest_rate_per_year = 10.00
intrest_rate_per_month = ((intrest_rate_per_year / 100) + 1) ** (1/12)
additional_monthly_increase = 00.00
duration_in_years = 5.0
duration_in_months = duration_in_years * 12.0

result = kapital_from_start * (intrest_rate_per_month) ** duration_in_months

print("\n\n######################################################\n")
print("Resulting kapital: " + str(result) + " $.")
print("\n######################################################\n\n")
```

> ################################################
>
> Resulting kapital: 80525.50000000012 $.
>
> ################################################

Also your naming convention looks to verbose to me, but that seems like another whole issue.

---

**EDIT**: Sorry for making this answer too long but in case someone steps here having the same problem and not understanding what is happening I found a nice graph from Wikipedia that ilustrates perfectly why your code was wrong. 
[image: Example of Frequency]

Comment: Nice summarize! I did however need the loop because this is actually to calculate my earnings from a equity fund where I will pay monthly additional money into it which also has to bet into the calculation. Otherwise the easier formula which you have put together would have been my way to. Thanks for the extra information with the graph, really makes things easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the f(uture)v(value) using [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.financial.html)

`from numpy import fv`

`fv(.1/12, 5*12, 0, 50000)`

(result) = `-82265.44673892927`

The `fv` signature is `fv(rate, nper, pmt, pv[, when])`

The amount compounded yearly would be:

```
>>> fv(.1,5,0,50000)
-80525.50000000003
```